# Google MAP API | Push Notification for Website

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, web-applications, google-api

I am using Google Maps API for a project whose functionality is something like below

Functionality achieved:

> When user sign in they see map and their current location is traced. Users can mark their favorite location and add a comment.

Functionality required and I need help in:

> When any user passes through any location in real time, then my web application should send a notification saying "you are someone's favorite place do you want to add comment and xyz..."

Can anyone help me even with a hint on how I can achieve this for the web application?

P.S: I am not using any mobile application for this purpose. This is a web application.

Comment: For apps or website that track and monitor the position of people and/or things, you should have a valid Asset Tracking license. Please refer to this Google Maps APIs pricing and plans documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're already set up with getting the user's location through the browser geolocation api when the page loads. My suggestion is to get the user's location again on a certain interval, every couple minutes maybe. If the new location is more than a little bit different than the previous location, send an ajax request to your server, see if the new location is near one of these favorite places, and if so, display a notification that they are near this place.

Comment: Can't I use real-time tracking of location as we do in Google Map and when they hit a mark location they will be notified?

Comment: How do you do real-time tracking of location in Google Map?